# Change font size in a column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a column in a DataGridView (WinForm application) that needs the font size and style changed. From the article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.font.aspx , I am thinking that the code below will get the result that I want (I am testing by changing the styling first):

```
this.dataGridViewMain.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(dataGridViewMain.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
```

But the code does not change anything. I also tried to add the code on the `RowPostPaint` event handler but still does not work. I know the font that is used by the program is set on the `DataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle` properties but I thought placing code in the `RowPostPaint` event will override that. Below is the code from the `RowPostPaint` event:

```
void dataGridViewMain_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridViewMain.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridViewMain.Rows)
    {
        int daysInShop = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Days in the shop"].Value);
        if (daysInShop > 4)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
        else if (daysInShop > 2)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
        }
        row.Height = 35;
    }

    this.dataGridViewMain.CurrentCell = null; // no row is selected when DGV is displayed
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I tested your first statement to change the column to itallics and it worked perfectly fine.
Note that i added that after the datagridview was already populated. Not before.

Comment: Interesting. I have set up the RowsDefaultCellStyle properties on the DataGridView to Verdana, 14.25pt, and Bold. And that style is what shows up. My code to italicize the column does not override that properties. Also I filled out the DataGridView with DataTable instead of creating my own column in the DataGridView (not sure if this has anything to do with the problem)

Comment: I also filled mine with a datatable.

Comment: This is a quite old thread, but still useful occasionally.
My small contribution is that it is not necessary to loop, you can use e->RowIndex to be more focussed, since you will get a call from every row.

Comment: Also, use PrePaint rather than PostPaint

Comment: I noticed in debugging that the row->DefaultCellStyle, allthough set before ShowDialog, was not set when in Pre- or PostPaint. This must explain why I could not get the style set in advance to work. Of course, it is extra nice to be able to adjust style dynamically based on content.

Answer (score 7):

Ok this is what I found out. Under `InitializeComponent()` there is this line:

```
dataGridViewCellStyle3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

When I comment that line out, then the code to italicize a column that is in `RowPostPaint` works fine. I then added the code below in the `RowPostPaint` so that other columns font are bold and have smaller size. I am still not quite sure why `DataGridView.Columns[colNumber].DefaultCellStyle.Font` does not override `dataGridViewCellStyle3`

```
 int colCount = dataGridViewMain.ColumnCount;

 for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
 {
     if(i != 3)
         this.dataGridViewMain.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 14F, FontStyle.Bold);
     else
         this.dataGridViewMain.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 25F, FontStyle.Bold);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Font size is read only so you would want to make a new font and set yourDataGridView.Font = new Font(name,size,style) here is more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx

Comment: Yes I have tried that before but for me the problem is that the styling does not even work, so I commented out the code for new Font

Comment: I tried to add the code after setting filling the DataGridView. Code: dataGridViewMain.DataSource = table;
Also tried to put the code in the RowPostPaint event. None of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView.Rows)
{
     if ( // your condition here )
     {
        dr.Cells[0].Style.Font = new Font( dataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
        dr.Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;      
        dr.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
     }
     else
     {     
      // It also may be a good idea to restore original settings
      // for the non selected rows just in case you re run this routine               
        dr.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
        dr.Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
        dr.Cells[0].Style.Font = dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Font;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is already answered and your post seems not to add any new information.

Answer (score -1):

Set `RowsDefaultCellStyle` to `null` after `InitializeComponent()`.

I think the `DataGridView` takes styles in the order grid/column/row. So if a row style is set it always overrides any column style.

In my view this is poor design - there is no need for a default row style at all!